# Autocomplete not showing function arguments that have default values in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

In xcode on a c++ project, is there any way to have autocomplete show the function arguments that have default values? Right now, if I have two functions:

```
void function1(int Val1, float Val2);
void function2(int Val1 = 0, float Val2 = 1.f);
```

autocomplete will list the function arguments when I start to call `function1`, but not when I call `function2`. Is there a way to change this? I'm using xcode 5.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I've figured out so far, I'll still happily award the bounty to anyone who elaborates on it or comes up with a better or more clever solution.

The solution I've got now is to define the function multiple times: one time without any default values, and then any number of times with default values and defined `inline`.

A definition with default values then calls the definition with the next-fewest number of default values, until we get down to the function call that actually does something:

```
void foo(int Val1, float Val2) { /* function details */ }

inline void foo(int Val1) {
    float Val2 = 1.f;
    foo(Val1, Val2);
}

inline void foo() {
    int Val1 = 0;
    foo(Val1);
}
```

Autocomplete will then show the different optional versions of `foo`, each with the respective set of arguments.